# Getting error while opening reports folder in Lightning

Tags: reports-folder

I have few reports in my org which were working fine since last release, now when i try to open a report folder from all reports section iam getting following error. Even it has access to all users and don't know why a sudden change without making any changes to my org?

Do we have any changes in latest salesforce release or is this any other issue?
Someone who knows solution can help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks In Advance.

This error is thrown only in Lightning view.

[image]

Comment: Turn on the server-side debug logging to see if you get more information there.

Comment: Debugs are turned on but iam not getting any log if i click on the report folder, it just throws the error attached above.

Comment: Since you have mentioned reports folder, kindly re-check all the folder sharing permissions for the current user who is accessing this report.

Comment: I am the owner of the Reports and as mentioned above permission access has been given to all users.

Answer (score 0):

During the salesforce summer 18 preview release, the folder sharing was disabled. Salesforce support is not sure why exactly this happened.

In order to solve this:

1.Switch to salesforce classic
2.Go to setup
3.Open 'Folder Sharing'
4.Make sure enable access levels for sharing report and dashboard folders is checked
After enabling this, report folders were accessible again